# How to Develop a Composite / Builder Design Pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, builder

I'm working on a java project that requires the build of composite objects. In short, I'm using a variation of the [Builder Pattern](http://patterns.instantinterfaces.nl/current/Refactoring-and-Design-Patterns-PAT-BLD.html) to build out an "experiment." I need to also create a builder to create the users from the experiment users field in the experiment model.

> The rub is that I'm not sure how to implement designing a [Composite Design Pattern](http://patterns.instantinterfaces.nl/current/Refactoring-and-Design-Patterns-PAT-PARS.html#PAT-PARS-COP) object to build out the `experiment.users` when I build out the experiment.

Not germane to the topic but I'm using SpringMVC on the front end and using JPA for the persistence layer...

`The Service`

```
public interface ExperimentService {

    public Experiment create( ExperimentDTO created );

    ... 

}
```

`The Controller`

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/experiment/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitCreateExperimentForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute(MODEL_ATTRIBUTE_EXPERIMENT) ExperimentDTO created, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    ...
    Experiment experiment = experimentService.create(created);

    ... 
}
```

Attempting to follow good design habits, I'm try to avoid building an [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/on-domain-driven-design-anemic-domain.html) by following the classic builder pattern within the experiment entity. However, I'm a bit stuck in figuring out the best workflow to call my UserBuilder Builder from the ExperimentBuilder...

`The Builder`

```
public interface Builder<T> {
public T build();
}
```

`Experiment Entity`

```
@Entity(name = "experiment")
public class Experiment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinTable(
        name = "experiment_participant",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "experiment_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "participant_id")
   )
   private Set<ExperimentUser> experimentUsers = new HashSet<>();

    /** fields ... getters ... setters .. **/

   public static class ExperimentBuilder implements Builder {

    private final Experiment experiment;
   /** fields ... **/

    public ExperimentBuilder( ... ) {
        experiment = new Experiment();

     /** ??? WIRE UP THE USERBUILDER HERE ??? ** **/ 

    }
```